# Send link of "ThisItem"

Tags: powerapps

I'm using powerapps to manage a budget. When an user submit a budget, I send a link to the person who validate budgets. How can I use the form link, to allowed validator to click and open form ?

Example :

```
Office365.SendEmail(
    LookUp(
        'DI - Portefeuilles';
        Title = DataCardValue11.Selected.Title;
        Controleur.Email
    );
    Concatenate(
        "Budget n°";
        Titre.Text
    );
    Concatenate(
        "Le budget n°";
        Titre.Text;
        "(";
        SharePointIntegration.Selected.'{Link}';
        ")";
        " attend votre validation."
    )
)
```

I tried "SharePointIntegration.Selected." and "ThisItem." with {Link} or {Path} but nothing is working.

My question is : is it possible, and if yes, how?

EDIT : I found that {Link} works if I submit my form before then reopen it and send the mail. Is there a way to do what I want at the first submit ?
I try to use the OnSucess, but I can't succeed.

Comment: Have you considered moving some functionality away from the PowerApps form and to something like Flow?  A validation flow could start when an item is created, and this is probably closer to the intended use of these tools.

Comment: That is what I was trying before your answer. What solution is best for you ? Flow seems hard to configure correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that SharePointIntegration.Selected looks at what item was selected (if any) on the list when the PowerApps form was opened.  This means that even when creating a new item, SharePointIntegration.Selected will return the properties of the last selected item.  I am not sure if this is intended behaviour but it is what it is.

In any case the solution to your problem is therefore to use SharePointForm1.LastSubmit.'{Link}' to retrieve the link to the newly created item after submission via the OnSuccess action.

Comment: This is working well. Is it possible to create a more useable link ? Like "Budget XXX", and when you click you open the {link} ? I try Launch, but I think it's not the good one.

Comment: Found ! Using {IsHtml:true} in the sendmail, and <a href=SharePointForm1.LastSubmit.'{Link}'> LINK</a> !